# get invalid latitude on base map get from google

Tags: qgis

I use c++ and qgis to make base layer from google map as below:

```
QgsDataSourceUri ds;
ds.setParam("type", "xyz");
ds.setParam("url", QString("https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=m&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}"));
ds.setParam("zmax", "18");
ds.setParam("zmin", "0");
layer = new QgsRasterLayer(uri.encode(), "basemap", "wms");
```

I found the problem: in qgis gui, when i add google maps (xyztiles layer), qgis show full map (Dotted line divides the upper and lower parts); but when i run this code, the result only show a upper part, could you explain for me? and what will i do to get full map

result fro qgis gui:

[image: result from qgis gui]

result from my code:
[image: result from my code]

Comment: Google maps  use WGS84 EPSG:4326 angular coords  ..  you are using metrical coords ..  you shoudl convert the coords properly between you SR ..

Comment: @ScaisEdge could you explain more detail or give me code example, i cannot figure out

Comment: Is pretty complex ..   if you don't know what are SR (System Reference) and types of coords. should you should  take e  deep tourabout this  ..

Comment: @ScaisEdge i've update my post, please see it

Comment: Your problem is clear to me  ..  but for try a solution we need  to know which is  the exact SR of your original map..  Which EPSG????

Comment: @ScaisEdge in qgis gui, layer properties show information from provider:
CRS EPSG:3857 - WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator - Projected
Extent -20037508.3427892439067364,-20037508.3427892550826073 : 20037508.3427892439067364,20037508.3427892439067364
Unit meters
then i change layer CRS to EPSG:4326 so get first image, in my code layer CRS default is EPSG:4326, i try get information about layer CRS but dont show anything, only bounding box is -180.0000000000000000,-85.0511287798066036 : 180.0000000000000000,85.0511287798066036 and result is second image

Comment: i think my problem seem in settings for request to google service, i try add open street map layer and get the same result, incorrent coordinate because the map show only upper part but the same bounding box

Comment: You have CRS EPSG:3857   .. is not CRS EPSG:4326  (google SR) .. .. then take a look on qgis for change SR (CSR)